Detecting Volatility Clusters in Time Series, Stock Returns (%) in particular
My primary objective is to detect the presence of volatility clusters in financial time series, stock returns (%) in particular. So, it can be translated into the detection of "conditional heteroskedasticity" in stock returns (%), itself; but not "conditional heteroskedasticity" in residuals arising from a model.
Under this circumstance, what statistical test would be appropriate?
And if there is an appropriate test, what would be the null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis? I think that it is important to have a set of hypothesis that can assess the presence or the absence of the volatility cluster, conditional heteroskedasticity.
Is "Engle’s ARCH test" appropriate for my purpose: to detect the volatility cluster? Or is it designed to test the statistical property of the residuals rather than the volatility of the time series itself?

I'm not sure which test is appropriate. However, one designed for residuals should be fine, since the volatility of the series itself is the same as the volatility of the residuals from the model $y = \mu + \varepsilon$
